# TCL how to use math::geometry library

Tags: math, geometry, tcl

I am new to TCl language, I have some question for using the *math* library. Do I need to include the *math::geometry* library before i use it ? like the way we do in C or C++. The function i need to use is `::math::geometry::lineSegmentsIntersect linesegment1 linesegment2`

I would really appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to load the package first. And of course have it installed first, as it is part of the tcllib and not always available in the core language.

Loading is usually done with the `package require` command as listed in the documentation of the [package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/math_geometry.html#synopsis).

```
package require math::geometry
```

Once you have it loaded, you can use the proc with the fully qualified name, e.g.:

```
puts [::math::geometry::lineSegmentsIntersect {1 0 1 1} {1 1 0 1}]
```

That prints 1, as the lines given intersect.

Comment: It's considered good practice to put all the `package require` lines needed for the code in a .tcl file at the top of the file so that you can see the requirements at a glance.